How can I infer return type for object based on parameter?
Let's say we have a function
def get_attr_wrapper(obj: object, attr: str) -> ???:
    return getattr(obj, attr)

How can I infer the return type of get_attr_wrapper based on the parameters given?
Maybe with a generic somehow?
For example, if I passed in
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: str

foo = Foo(bar="baz")

rv = get_attr_wrapper(foo, "bar")

In our desired scenario, rv would be inferred by Python's type checker as being of type string.

You can use generics to make the return type of a function depend on the type of input parameters, but not on the runtime value of those parameters - since those are runtime values. The linter or compiler cannot infer the type of get_attr_wrapper based on the runtime value of attr. In the example, you can argue the value must be 'bar' and could be inferred, but that's only because that happens to be the runtime value in this example - it's not generally known what the type of getattr(obj, attr) would be, nor can it be known. The best you can do is object.

in a language that might support it, you could maybe do something with discriminated unions, but that would require the obj parameter to be a union of those types

Maybe I don’t understand what you’re trying to do but why can’t you just use type(rv)

@Marichyasana this implicit context here is that the OP is using python type annotations and the type system along with some static type checker, like mypy and pyright. at runtime, that is how you would do it in python, but this is for the purpose of static analysis tools

Your assertion that "rv would be inferred by Python's type checker as being of type string" is false. Return type of getattr is in fact Any so it follows that get_attr_wrapper as implemented will also return Any.

@metatoaster I'll rephrase, that is a question at the end, not an assertion.

In any case, this is still an open question for mypy, please refer to this python/mypy#11142.

@metatoaster even if that were implemented, it sill wouldn' work with an object type annotation for the parameter

So, there's no real way to find the type from a __getattr__ call. That said, it is possible to convince the type checker you have a slightly different object structure, and then infer the type based on a given string.
TypedDict objects allow for getting by string rather than attribute, and still inferring the type. We can use cast to "pretend" that Foo is actually a TypedDict, and implement __getitem__ in the same way as get_attr_wrapper:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypedDict, cast

class FooDict(TypedDict):
    bar: str

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: str

    def __getitem__(self, attr:str):
        # Behavior of get_attr_wrapper
        return getattr(self, attr)

foo = cast(FooDict, Foo(bar="baz"))

rv = foo["bar"]
print(rv)

Hope this is useful!

This is a really great answer. I wasn't aware of TypedDict existing but I can actually use this in place of a dataclass without even needing to cast anything. So this does actually answer my question directly. Thanks for posting this.

while using a typed dict is a reasonable suggestion, using cast this way is not
